# Image loading from https:// protocol but not loading from http:// protocol

Tags: ios, http, https, uiimageview

I am trying to upload image using `RemoteImageView` in my imageView. But for some reasons, if the image has the `https://` protocol URL then the imageView loads fine but if the images have `http://` protocol they do not load throwing error. Here is a piece of code,

```
 [_imageView loadImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_news.imageURL] withCompleteBlock:^(UIImage *image) {
        [_indicator stopAnimating];
        [_indicator removeFromSuperview];
    } withErrorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Could not uplad the picture");
        [_indicator stopAnimating];
        [_indicator removeFromSuperview];

    }];
```

//Here _imageView is instance of RemoteImageView.
//This image will load

[image]

//but the image below will not load

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Jay Bhalani. But I wanted the users to see the whole image URLs to compare the issue, I am not sure if they will be able to compare the URLs this way.

Comment: Here are the URLs for the images above :  Image on top has https:// protocol whereas image on the bottom has http:// protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is App Transport Security, new in iOS 9. See the section on [NSAppTransportSecurity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33)  for details on how to configure it if required. The recommended solution is to move all of your traffic to HTTPS.

Comment: There must be a duplicate for this.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree. But I couldn't find it. I can't even find Apple's tech note that explained it.

Comment: @rmaddy I think they changed NSAppTransportSecurity (not exactly sure) but the property list has only two properties, (i) Exception Domains and (ii) Allow Arbitrary Loads. I enable Allow Arbitray Loads